# Devexpress errors in IE

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I have a complete ASP.NET that makes heavy usage of your DevExpress ASPx  suite of controls. Grids, text boxes, round panels etc.

THe site works flawlessly in Chrome, Firefox however in IE some UI does not function. Example, i have an ASPxComboBox control. In IE it doesn't "Drop down".

Using F12 developer tools on the console line the following shows as the error code when the dropdown should fire

SCRIPT87: Invalid argument. 
DXR.axd?r=1_42-DSzC3, line 1268 character

The function is below, line 1268 is line 5 in the code below

```
function _aspxCreateStyleSheetInDocument(doc) {
if(__aspxIE)
 return doc.createStyleSheet();
else {
var styleSheet = doc.createElement("STYLE");
_aspxGetChildByTagName(doc, "HEAD", 0).appendChild(styleSheet);
 return styleSheet.sheet;
 }
}
```

Any suggestions where to start ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is resource merging enabled in web.config?

```xml
<devExpress>
...
    <compression enableHtmlCompression="false" enableCallbackCompression="true"  
                 enableResourceCompression="true" enableResourceMerging="true" />
...
</devExpress>
```

Answer (score 4):

This issue is a specific of the IE browser (it can be encountered when too many stylesheet links are registered within a page). To resolve this issue, it is recommended that you enable “**Resource Merging**” http://help.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument6911 option.

If **AutoFormats/Themes** are used, deploy controls skin via the «**ASPxThemeDeployer**” http://help.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument7485 tool in the “**Only skin files**” mode.

See Also:

http://www.devexpress.com/kb=K18487